# How to change the color of one or more element that is part of a SVG pattern?

Tags: svg

I have the following SVG code which draws many squares:

```html
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0,0,100%,100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <defs>
      <pattern id="smallGrid" width="1.388888888888889%" height="5%" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
       <path fill="#2e99e5" d="M0 0h960v960H0z" stroke="gray" stroke-width="0.5"/>
      </pattern>
      <pattern id="grid" width="8.333333333333333%" height="50%" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
       <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#smallGrid)"/>
       <path fill="none" d="M0 0h960v960H0z" stroke="gray" stroke-width="2" />
      </pattern>
     </defs>
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grid)" />
    </svg>
```

Is there a way to select the first 3 `<path fill="#2e99e5" d="M0 0h960v960H0z" stroke="gray" stroke-width="0.5"/>`
 and change the color?

Comment: What first 3 are you talking about? There's only 2 path elements in your markup.

Comment: Well, if you notice the full grid have 1,440 small squares, I'm talking about them. But what I really want is to be able to change the color of a single square at a determined moment.

Comment: Then you'll need to draw them individually, patterns repeat identically, that's their function.

Comment: Really? I wanted to avoid 1,440 dom elements, that's why I used SVG.

Comment: But you only want to highlight a few of them so draw them separately on top.

Comment: You *could* use a filter - but it makes more sense to follow Robert's suggestion

Comment: Is there a chance you know how to accomplish the same result drawing every single square?